# Unable to Parse the WSDL

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2apex

[Here is the link for the WSDL](http://www.knowwho.info/Services/ElectedOfficialsDirectoryService.asmx?WSDL)

I am getting the following Error:

**Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Found more than one wsdl:binding. WSDL with multiple binding not supported**

Comment: here's a reference blog on how to resolve this http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/consuming-external-webservice-in-apex/

Answer (score 1):

Check your WSDL for multiple instances of the `<binding>` tag, and remove all but the one you intend the web service to make the call to.

If you require multiple bindings, you will need to split your WSDL into separate files and run the wsdl2apex tool on each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

Wsdl2Apex doesn't currently support Soap 1.2, so you need to remove the soap12 bindings and leave the Soap 1.1 elements.

Here is an Apex wrapper class generated for the Soap 1.1 elements:

```
//Generated by FuseIT WSDL2Apex (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx)
//Methods Included: GetDistricts, GetPeople, GetCommittees, SearchByDistrict, SearchByChamber, SearchByID, SearchByCommittee, SearchByAddress, GetService
// Primary Port Class Name: ElectedOfficialsDirectoryServiceSoap    
public class wwwKnowwhoInfo {
    public class ElectedOfficialsDirectoryServiceSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.knowwho.info/Services/ElectedOfficialsDirectoryService.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','wwwKnowwhoInfo'};

        public String GetCommittees(String InputString) {
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetCommittees_element request_x = new wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetCommittees_element();
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetCommitteesResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.InputString = InputString;
            Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetCommitteesResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetCommitteesResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.knowwho.info/GetCommittees',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'GetCommittees',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'GetCommitteesResponse',
                'wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetCommitteesResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.GetCommitteesResult;
        }

        public String GetDistricts(String InputString) {
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetDistricts_element request_x = new wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetDistricts_element();
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetDistrictsResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.InputString = InputString;
            Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetDistrictsResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetDistrictsResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.knowwho.info/GetDistricts',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'GetDistricts',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'GetDistrictsResponse',
                'wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetDistrictsResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.GetDistrictsResult;
        }

        public String GetPeople(String InputString) {
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetPeople_element request_x = new wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetPeople_element();
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetPeopleResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.InputString = InputString;
            Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetPeopleResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetPeopleResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.knowwho.info/GetPeople',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'GetPeople',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'GetPeopleResponse',
                'wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetPeopleResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.GetPeopleResult;
        }

        public String GetService(String InputString) {
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetService_element request_x = new wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetService_element();
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetServiceResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.InputString = InputString;
            Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetServiceResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetServiceResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.knowwho.info/GetService',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'GetService',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'GetServiceResponse',
                'wwwKnowwhoInfo.GetServiceResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.GetServiceResult;
        }

        public String SearchByAddress(String InputString) {
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByAddress_element request_x = new wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByAddress_element();
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByAddressResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.InputString = InputString;
            Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByAddressResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByAddressResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.knowwho.info/SearchByAddress',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByAddress',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByAddressResponse',
                'wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByAddressResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.SearchByAddressResult;
        }

        public String SearchByChamber(String InputString) {
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByChamber_element request_x = new wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByChamber_element();
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByChamberResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.InputString = InputString;
            Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByChamberResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByChamberResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.knowwho.info/SearchByChamber',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByChamber',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByChamberResponse',
                'wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByChamberResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.SearchByChamberResult;
        }

        public String SearchByCommittee(String InputString) {
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByCommittee_element request_x = new wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByCommittee_element();
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByCommitteeResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.InputString = InputString;
            Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByCommitteeResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByCommitteeResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.knowwho.info/SearchByCommittee',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByCommittee',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByCommitteeResponse',
                'wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByCommitteeResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.SearchByCommitteeResult;
        }

        public String SearchByDistrict(String InputString) {
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByDistrict_element request_x = new wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByDistrict_element();
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByDistrictResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.InputString = InputString;
            Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByDistrictResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByDistrictResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.knowwho.info/SearchByDistrict',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByDistrict',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByDistrictResponse',
                'wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByDistrictResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.SearchByDistrictResult;
        }

        public String SearchByID(String InputString) {
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByID_element request_x = new wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByID_element();
            wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByIDResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.InputString = InputString;
            Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByIDResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByIDResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.knowwho.info/SearchByID',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByID',
                'http://www.knowwho.info/',
                'SearchByIDResponse',
                'wwwKnowwhoInfo.SearchByIDResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.SearchByIDResult;
        }
    }
    public class GetCommittees_element {
        public String InputString;
        private String[] InputString_type_info = new String[]{'InputString','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'InputString'};
    }
    public class GetCommitteesResponse_element {
        public String GetCommitteesResult;
        private String[] GetCommitteesResult_type_info = new String[]{'GetCommitteesResult','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetCommitteesResult'};
    }
    public class GetDistricts_element {
        public String InputString;
        private String[] InputString_type_info = new String[]{'InputString','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'InputString'};
    }
    public class GetDistrictsResponse_element {
        public String GetDistrictsResult;
        private String[] GetDistrictsResult_type_info = new String[]{'GetDistrictsResult','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetDistrictsResult'};
    }
    public class GetPeople_element {
        public String InputString;
        private String[] InputString_type_info = new String[]{'InputString','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'InputString'};
    }
    public class GetPeopleResponse_element {
        public String GetPeopleResult;
        private String[] GetPeopleResult_type_info = new String[]{'GetPeopleResult','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetPeopleResult'};
    }
    public class GetService_element {
        public String InputString;
        private String[] InputString_type_info = new String[]{'InputString','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'InputString'};
    }
    public class GetServiceResponse_element {
        public String GetServiceResult;
        private String[] GetServiceResult_type_info = new String[]{'GetServiceResult','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetServiceResult'};
    }
    public class SearchByAddress_element {
        public String InputString;
        private String[] InputString_type_info = new String[]{'InputString','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'InputString'};
    }
    public class SearchByAddressResponse_element {
        public String SearchByAddressResult;
        private String[] SearchByAddressResult_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByAddressResult','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByAddressResult'};
    }
    public class SearchByChamber_element {
        public String InputString;
        private String[] InputString_type_info = new String[]{'InputString','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'InputString'};
    }
    public class SearchByChamberResponse_element {
        public String SearchByChamberResult;
        private String[] SearchByChamberResult_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByChamberResult','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByChamberResult'};
    }
    public class SearchByCommittee_element {
        public String InputString;
        private String[] InputString_type_info = new String[]{'InputString','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'InputString'};
    }
    public class SearchByCommitteeResponse_element {
        public String SearchByCommitteeResult;
        private String[] SearchByCommitteeResult_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByCommitteeResult','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByCommitteeResult'};
    }
    public class SearchByDistrict_element {
        public String InputString;
        private String[] InputString_type_info = new String[]{'InputString','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'InputString'};
    }
    public class SearchByDistrictResponse_element {
        public String SearchByDistrictResult;
        private String[] SearchByDistrictResult_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByDistrictResult','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByDistrictResult'};
    }
    public class SearchByID_element {
        public String InputString;
        private String[] InputString_type_info = new String[]{'InputString','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'InputString'};
    }
    public class SearchByIDResponse_element {
        public String SearchByIDResult;
        private String[] SearchByIDResult_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByIDResult','http://www.knowwho.info/','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.knowwho.info/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'SearchByIDResult'};
    }
}
```